# Remove geoJSON from Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, layer

I have a function who retrieves a JSON with earthquakes data, that I add to a Leaflet map, that retrieves the JSON again after 10 seconds (for refreshing data):

```
function fetchQuake() {
        fetch('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson')
        .then(function(res) {
            if (res.ok === true) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                alert('Geojson request failed.');
            }
        })
        .then(function(quake) {
                L.geoJSON(quake, {
                    style: function(feature) {
                        return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
                    },
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
                    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                            radius: 8,
                            fillColor: "#ff7800",
                            color: "#000",
                            weight: 1,
                            opacity: 1,
                            fillOpacity: 0.8
                        });
                    }
                }).addTo(map);

            myQuakeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                fetchQuake();
            }, 10000);
        });
}
```

And a function who clears the map from these points:

```
function clearQuake() {
    clearTimeout(myQuakeTimeout);
    L.geoJSON().clearLayers();
}
```

With these code, the timeout stops, but the earthquakes points don't go away from the map, what is the problem?

Comment: Enrico, could you please update your question being more specific on where and how do you call the `clearQuake()` function? Thanks!

Comment: The functions are called by a button that executes them alternatively, first it executes fetchQuake to add quake points, and then it executes clearQuake to remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code, your `clearQuake()` function is never called, so `L.geoJSON().clearLayers()` is never executed.

That's the reason your points don't go away from the map.

If you want to remove the previous points before adding the new fetched ones, you could do something like:

```
/* ... */
.then(function(quake) {

    L.geoJSON().clearLayers();

    L.geoJSON(quake, {
        /* ... */
    }).addTo(map);

    myQuakeTimeout = setTimeout(fetchQuake, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please give me some feedback and/or the reasons for downvoting? Thanks!

Comment: Immediate issue seems to be trying to clear a new empty group, instead of the previously created Layer Group. As for `clearQuake`, OP's last sentence implies that it is called, possibly by external means, to stop the chain and flush everything. It is true that it looks strange not trying to clear before adding new data at each timeout.

Comment: Thanks @ghybs :) Well, clearing an empty group shouldn't be an issue but it could be avoided with a single comparison. Also, imho, OP's last sentence doesn't imply `clearQuake()` being called at all. He's not using `setInterval` but `setTimeout`, so if Promise fails the *timeout* will stop but `clearQuake` won't be called. We can make assumptions, of course, but the truth is the shared code doesn't show how `L.geoJSON().clearLayers()` is supposed to be called...